# How to get user activity in discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot that will write to the chat what the user is playing, but even when the game is running, None is displayed all the time

What am I doing wrong?

Working code:

```
from discord.ext import tasks
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.presences = True


class MyClient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in as')
        print(self.user.name)
        print(self.user.id)
        print('------')

    @tasks.loop(seconds=5)
    async def activity_task(self, message):
        mentions = message.mentions
        if len(mentions) == 0:
            await message.reply("Remember to give someone to get status!")
        else:
            activ = mentions[0].activity
            if activ is None:
                await message.reply("None")
            else:
                await message.reply(activ.name)

    @activity_task.before_loop
    async def before_my_task(self):
        await self.wait_until_ready()

    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.content.startswith('!status'):
            self.activity_task.start(message)


client = MyClient(intents=intents)
client.run('token')
```

Comment: You need to enabled the presence [intent](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#presence-intent)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ceres said, you need to allow intents.
Go to your developer's page https://discord.com/developers/applications, and go to the bot. Scroll down a bit, and you'll see this: [image]
Turn on `presence and server members intent`.

Now, in your code, you'll have to add this in the beginning:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
```

Change your bot startup code to this

```
client = MyClient(intents=intents)
```

Now, with the intents, you want the OTHER person's activity.
So, in the `activity_task` method, you can't use `message.author`, as that will return whoever sent the message, not who you're mentioning.

Change it to this:

```
async def activity_task(self, message):
        mentions = message.mentions
        if len(mentions) == 0:
            await message.reply("Remember to give someone to get status!")
        else:
            activ = mentions[0].activity
            if activ == None:
                await messag.reply("None")
            else:    
                await message.reply(activ.name)
```

Now, if you do `!status @[valid ping here]`, it should return whatever they're doing. Must note: it MUST be a valid ping.

Comment: You also have to enable them in the code.

Comment: Yep, added that. @ŁukaszKwieciński

Comment: He made his own client class, so instead of `bot = discord.Client(intents=intents)` it should be `client = MyClient(intents=intents)`

Comment: I added and enabled everything that was described above, but the bot still does not work correctly

Comment: @Yolixer are you trying to get your own game playing or someone elses?

Comment: @Yolixer also did you save your discord bot changes?

Comment: @PythonPikachu8 Yes, I save bot changes and I trying to get other game name

Comment: @Yolixer Well in your code, you're actually getting your own game status.

Comment: @PythonPikachu8 I update code, but its still doesn't work. When I use `!status @ping` I keep getting None anyway

Comment: Could you put a picture?@Yolixer

Comment: @PythonPikachu8 [link](https://i.imgur.com/Lg5ppmi.png) pic of pinging. Also added the corrected code

Comment: Hmm, lemme take a closer look.

Comment: @Yolixer when you mean status, you do mean when it says `Playing ... (like Minecraft)` below their nickname right?

Comment: @PythonPikachu8 yes, like playing a game or listening something on spotify

Comment: @Yolixer i changed something, try it now.

Comment: @PythonPikachu8 It still doesn't work, but look at this [pic](https://i.imgur.com/3ES2nJM.png), I think the problem is that the bot thinks that ALL users are offline

Comment: Hmm, let's try using member intent. Do `intents = discord.Intents.all()`

Comment: @Yolixer ok code is fixed a bit, try now.

Comment: @PythonPikachu8 Yes, it works, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Yolixer no problem!